# API for validating user credentials (username/password) in PING

Tags: ping, pingfederate

Is there an API in Ping Federate/ Ping One to validate user credentials - username and password?

Here is a scenario in which I would like to use it:

1. user logs in via SAML SSO to my web application
2. certain application feature requires that the user credentials are validated again (to sign-off some operation)

SAML SSO does not make it easy to re-validate user credentials without logging out from application, users passwords are obviously not stored in the application so the only way to validate credentials is to send them via some API to Ping to validate - however I was unable to find such API in Ping.

For example, OKTA (which offers similar services as Ping) does provide such API:

```
curl -v -X POST \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
  "username": "dade.murphy@example.com",
  "password": "correcthorsebatterystaple"
}' "https://${yourOktaDomain}/api/v1/authn"
```

I am looking for something similar in Ping.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - there are two options in PingFederate for this:

1. **Authentication API** - This enables clients to authenticate users via a REST API instead of having the adapters present login templates directly. More details here: https://docs.pingidentity.com/bundle/pingfederate-102/page/elz1592262150859.html
2. **OAuth Resource owner password credentials grant type** - If you're just looking to validate a username + password combination you could leverage PingFederate's support of OAuth ROPC grant type. It allows you to POST the credentials and get back an Access Token if it was successful. More details here: https://docs.pingidentity.com/bundle/pingfederate-102/page/lzn1564003025072.html

Answer (score 0):

Karolbe, you may also wish to take a look at Adaptive Authentication feature provided by PingFederate which directly answers your second requirement as provided by you above, i.e. - certain application feature requires that the user credentials are validated again (to sign-off some operation). [Here is the reference from PingIdentity website](https://www.pingidentity.com/content/dam/ping-6-2-assets/Assets/technical-briefs/en/3271-adaptive-authentication-and-authorization.pdf).  Adaptive authentication and authorization allow you to evaluate contextual, behavioral and correlated data to make a more informed decision and gain a higher level of assurance about a user’s identity, which is what your requirement 2) is asking for. Typical use case could be, say a user tries to access a high valued application, or tries to login after a configured idle time, Adaptive authentication will force user to present authentication credentials again.